# Can ASP.NET 5 class library target .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I can easily create a vNext class library that compiles the source to .NET 4.5 and ASP.NET Core. I can also create a target for PCL (`net40+sl50+wp80+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10`). The problem is that I would like my library to also target 3.5 but adding `net35` to the `"frameworks"` list adds an entry in the references but expanding that shows that it actually imports .NET 4.5 assemblies so the compiled result is not targeting .NET 3.5 but instead 4.5...

Is is possible for the vNext class library to target .NET 3.5?

Comment: There will come a time in the future where vNext means something else. The answer that is marked as accepted will eventually become wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The references displayed on VS2015 show indeed a link to .NET 4
[image]


But the generated NuGet shows 3.5 :
[image]

However I was not able to test of this really works when running on Windows with only 3.5 installed.